# how can I stop it from printing duplicate?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm I've created the below shopping cart, however, I'm trying to print the elements of the basket inside the HTML, but it's printing duplicated. If I add another element to the basket, it prints the new one + the previous one, even if the previous one is already printed.
Really appreciate the help, i'm new with JS, so struggling a bit.
thank you

//list of products

```
let products = [
  {
    name: "Logitech Pebble M350 Pink",
    tag: "mouse",
    price: 15.99,
    count: ""
  },
  {
    name: "Logitech K380 Multi-Device Bluetooth Keyboard",
    tag: "keyboard",
    price: 20.99,
    count: ""
  },
  {
    name: "Anker SoundCore min",
    tag: "speaker",
    price: 22.99,
    count: ""
  }
];

//ADD
function add() {
  let quantity = document.getElementsByClassName("quantity");
  let totalPrice = [];
  let nameCount = 0;
  let basket = [];
  let basketSentence = document.getElementById("yourBasket");
  for (let i = 0; i < quantity.length; i++) {
    products[i].count = quantity[i].value;
  }
  for (var name in products) {
    nameCount = nameCount + 1;
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < nameCount; i++) {
    totalPrice[i] = products[i].price * products[i].count;

    var sum = totalPrice.reduce(function(a, b) {
      return a + b;
    }, 0);
    if (products[i].count != 0) {
      basket.push(products[i]);
      const newLi = document.createElement("li");

      newLi.innerText = products[i].count + " " + products[i].name;
      if (yourBasket.innerText != newLi.innerText) {
        yourBasket.append(newLi);
        console.log(yourBasket.innerText);
      }
    }
    document.getElementById("total-value").innerHTML = sum;
  }
}

//REMOVE
let removeBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".remove");
let quantity = document.querySelectorAll(".quantity");

removeBtn.forEach(function(check) {
  check.addEventListener("click", checkIndex);
});

function checkIndex(event) {
  let totalPrice = [];
  let nameCount = 0;
  var index = Array.from(removeBtn).indexOf(event.target);
  console.log(index);
  quantity[index].value = "";
  products[index].count = quantity[index].value;
  console.log(products[index].count);

  for (var name in products) {
    nameCount = nameCount + 1;
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < nameCount; i++) {
    totalPrice[i] = products[i].price * products[i].count;

    var sum = totalPrice.reduce(function(a, b) {
      return a + b;
    }, 0);

    document.getElementById("total-value").innerHTML = sum;
  }
}
```

Comment: Try to add `basketSentence.innerHTML = "";` just after `let basketSentence = document.getElementById("yourBasket");`. Also, you should probably use `basketSentence` instead of `yourBasket`

Comment: @Sara can we have the full html? it's a bit hard to figure out what's going on without the html part. Also, you are missing the ADD click handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Explanation

The solution is to reset the text of the basket before you start appending again.

Add the line  `yourBasket.innerHTML = "";`  before the for loop.

The problem was that `append` was appending text. What you want is to actually clear the basket, and re-append all the totals of all the products.

**Excerpt:**

```
  yourBasket.innerHTML = ""; //THIS IS THE LINE
  for (let i = 0; i < nameCount; i++) {
    totalPrice[i] = products[i].price * products[i].count;
```

**Full code for Add:**

```
//ADD    

function add() {
  let quantity = document.getElementsByClassName("quantity");
  let totalPrice = [];
  let nameCount = 0;
  let basket = [];

   let basketSentence = document.getElementById("yourBasket");
  for (let i = 0; i < quantity.length; i++) {
    products[i].count = quantity[i].value;
  }
  for (var name in products) {
    nameCount = nameCount + 1;
  }

  yourBasket.innerHTML = ""; //(newLi);
  for (let i = 0; i < nameCount; i++) {
    totalPrice[i] = products[i].price * products[i].count;

    var sum = totalPrice.reduce(function(a, b) {
      return a + b;
    }, 0);
    if (products[i].count != 0) {
      basket.push(products[i]);
      const newLi = document.createElement("li");

      newLi.innerText = products[i].count + " " + products[i].name;
      if (yourBasket.innerText != newLi.innerText) {
        yourBasket.append(newLi);
        console.log(yourBasket.innerText);
      }
    }
    document.getElementById("total-value").innerHTML = sum;
  }
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4zyd1sow/4/

Comment: thank you! it worked. just a quick question, wouldn't it be possible to analyse if yourBasket.innerText already existed and if it did, not to print again? If so, how would I do that in the context of this problem? thank you

Comment: @Sara Hi,  could you please accept the answer. About your question, you would have to parse the actual text of the basket and change the values.You could iterate through the `<li>` elements and change their values. 

But it would be too much work without much  of a gain.

Comment: @Sara No prob! When you have time please accept an answer. Thanks